# How to check is there any negative term in a large list?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

I want to check if a data set of size $10^{10}$ contains any non-positive elements.  `Positive[Name of dataset]` returns a list of `True` and `False` of length $10^{10}$.  I want only a single `True` if all terms of that dataset are positive and `False` otherwise.

Comment: `VectorQ[list, Positive]`?

Comment: Use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) as in `And @@ Positive[list]`

Comment: How do you want to deal with terms that are exactly zero? Do you need all terms to be positive (use `Positive`), or do you need all terms to be zero or positive (use `NonNegative`)?

Answer (score 14):

Alternate solution:

```
list = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
Min[list] >= 0
```

Comment: ...i.e. `NonNegative[Min[list]]`.

Comment: Very good solution! This avoids lists of Booleans and hence allows for vectorization. (Boolean arrays cannot be packed.)

Comment: This is about 100 times faster than any of the other solutions. Impressive!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

Since you have a very large list, you should look at the timing

```
list = RandomReal[1, 10^6];

(And @@ Positive[list]) // AbsoluteTiming (* Hanlon *)

(* {0.050573, True} *)

VectorQ[list, Positive] // AbsoluteTiming (* J.M. *)

(* {0.261642, True} *)

(AnyTrue[list, Negative] // Not) // AbsoluteTiming (* Morbo *)

(* {0.324062, True} *)

And @@ (list /. {x_?Negative -> False, 
 x_?Positive -> True}) // AbsoluteTiming (* Alrubaie *)

(* {1.00664, True} *)
```

**EDIT:** As suggested by mjw, encountering a nonpositive value early in the list significantly alters the results.

```
list2 = ReplacePart[list, 1000 -> -1];

(And @@ Positive[list2]) // AbsoluteTiming (*Hanlon*)

(* {0.277642, False} *)

VectorQ[list2, Positive] // AbsoluteTiming (*J.M.*)

(* {0.000223, False} *)

(AnyTrue[list2, Negative] // Not) // AbsoluteTiming (*Morbo*)

(* {0.000262, False} *)

And @@ (list2 /. {x_?Negative -> False, 
     x_?Positive -> True}) // AbsoluteTiming (*Alrubaie*)

(* {1.43026, False} *)
```

Comment: Looks like your method is five times faster than the next best!  Can you give some insight into why this is?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, and I guess this depends on the probability of any entry being negative, it may make sense for the algorithm to stop as soon as it finds a negative (or non-positive) element in the list.

Comment: @mjw, `And[]` does short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @J. M.  Thank you!  I see.  So are the other methods (not using `And[]`) actually going through the whole list?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive the short-circuit only works efficiently if the listable `Positive` is evaluated lazily. Do you happen to know if Mathematica does any lazy evaluation internally when it detects a condition like what's done in Bob's solution? That would be great to construct efficient algorithms.

Comment: @Bob,  Thank you for your edit.  Why, though, does it take longer for your method to work when there is a negative entry?  I would have thought that in each case, it would take the same amount of time to go through the whole list.

Comment: @Roman, I do not believe that any lazy evaluation is being done. My comment was more to point out that an evaluation like `And[True, True, False, True, True, ... True]` will finish at once (and similar remarks apply for `Or[]`). Perhaps one can judiciously use `Catch[]/Throw[]`if an early-return test for long lists is desired.

Comment: Ahh, this is an interesting test on timings and on the differences which may or may not be faster. intriguing! thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, maybe this is too simple, but works for exactly what you're doing:

```
data = Table[RandomReal[{-1,1}],{i,1,1000}];
AnyTrue[data,Negative] // Not
(*False*)

data2 = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 10^2}];
AnyTrue[data2, Negative] // Not
(*True*)
```

Comment: `AllTrue[data, Positive]` to get the sign right. Or use `Not` on your solution.

Comment: @Roman - the poster is using `AnyTrue` not `AllTrue`

Comment: Yes @BobHanlon . In order to invert his solution to what the OP wants you have to either `Not@AnyTrue[data,Negative]` or (simpler) `AllTrue[data,Positive]` or `AllTrue[data,NonNegative]`.

Comment: ah, signs are reversed, missed that part. I updated the code to reflect questioners exact question.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, -5, -6, -7};

list /. {x_?Negative -> True, x_?Positive -> False}
```